# CVS checkout on Jenkins via CVS plugin much slower than CVS checkout on command line or via post-build script

Tags: performance, jenkins, cvs

I have configured a Jenkins project (test_cvs) via the CVS plugin to checkout a folder; lets call it CVSFOLDER.  The build reports the checkout command (on console output) as:

cvs checkout -D "29 Nov 2013 11:40:33 -0800" -d test_cvs CVSFOLDER

It takes 20 minutes for this checkout to complete.
If I run the same command manually on the same machine and folder where Jenkins is running, it takes 4 minutes.
Similarly, if I run the same command in a post-build script in Jenkins, it takes 4 minutes.

Does anyone know the reason that checking out via the CVS plugin takes 5x the time?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this question as well. In my case it's even worth: shell takes literally a second whilst jenkins takes 5 minutes.

Comment: Which OS? Which Jenkins / CVS version? Have you checked particular option(s)?
Wipe out the workspace, try only `Prune Empty Directories` and `Show all CVS output`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is because Jenkins uses it's own built in CVS client.

There are a few related open issues for this:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18539

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18330